# how to run exsisting django project in docker?

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to containerize my existing django project, which works just fine in my local machine.

dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM django
ADD . /
WORKDIR /site
RUN pip install django-elasticsearch-dsl==0.5.1
RUN pip install tika==1.19
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

i was able to create an image using :

```
docker build -t test1 .
```

and was able to create a container using the image by command :

```
docker run -d --name test1 -p 8000:8000 test1
```

as a result, i can see that the container test1 is up and running

Now, my understanding is if i do localhost:8000 in my browser, i should be able to see the view the required pages.

However, I don't see it.

I've have tried similar solutions available in stackoverflow, yet no success.

Comment: add `EXPOSE 8000` entry to the dockerfile

Comment: `You don't see it`, then what you see? Any error, and also `docker logs test1`?

Comment: though the container is up and running,  `docker logs test1` does not throw any log details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This image is officially deprecated in favor of the standard python
>   image, and will receive no further updates after 2016-12-31 (Dec 31,
>   2016). Please adjust your usage accordingly.
>
> For most usages of this image, it was already not bringing in django
>   from this image, but actually from your project's requirements.txt, so
>   the only "value" being added here was the pre-installing of
>   mysql-client, postgresql-client, and sqlite3 for various uses of the
>   django framework.

For example, a Dockerfile similar to the following would be a good starting point for a Django project using PostgreSQL:

```
FROM python:3.4

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

[source](https://hub.docker.com/_/django/)

**PS:** your `Dockerfile` is complaining about `manage.py` is not found